# Show existence of linear transformation from subset to subspace embedded in $\mathbb{F}_2^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

Assume I have a *subset* $X$ (not necessarily a subspace) of $\mathbb{F}_2^n$, of size $\leq 2^{n-1}$. It seems likely to me that there should exist a bijective linear transformation taking $X$ to a subset $Y$ contained in the $(n -1)$-dimensional subspace $V \subset \mathbb{F}_2^n$, being isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_2^{n-1}$ (i.e. $V$ is the embedding of $\mathbb{F}_2^{n-1}$ inside $\mathbb{F}_2^n$). However, I'm finding this hard to argue, since almost all statements I've found that could be somewhat relevant for this is based on linear transformations between sub-*spaces* or affine spaces.

As per Marc van Leeuwen's comment below, an alternative statement of the problem, which is probably clearer, is the following. Assume $X$ spans the entire space $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ (since if not, the solution is trivial). What I'm looking for then, is a linear map $f$ whose restriction to $X$ is injective and equal to $Y$.

Any idea how one might attack this? I've been thinking about some sort of counting argument and the pigeonhole-principle, but I'm finding it tricky. A non-constructive proof would be just fine.

Comment: I can understand you want to deal with a *subset* and not with a **subspace**, but then why in the world would you want to have a *linear map* embedding your set into a a hyperplane (=proper subspace of maximal dimension, in this case)?? Why not merely a sets map? Perhaps giving a little more background will make things easier to understand...

Comment: Well, if we only required the existence of a (set)-bijection between $X$ and $Y$, the statement would of course be trivial. The reason for wanting a linear map has to do with computational reasons.

Comment: Hmmm....I don't think it is foing to be feasible or very easy to do, if possible at all.

Comment: Your question could be stated more clearly. One may assume that $X$ spans the whole space (otherwise the problem is trivially solved with $Y=X$). I suppose you want a linear map $f$ defined on the whole space such that its restriction to $X$ is injective. Note that $f$ cannot itself be injective since linear maps preserve spans, and the span of the image $Y$ of $X$ is supposed to _not_ be the whole space, so for dimension reasons $f$ must have nonzero kernel. You just want all elements of $X$ to be non-congruent modulo the kernel of$~f$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Yes, I guess that is probably a better way of looking at it. Thx! I'll add that to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to prove appears not to be true.

Note that if $X$ spans the whole space but one wants (as you do) to obtain that $Y=f(X)$ does not span the whole space, then $f$ cannot itself be injective (hence for dimension reasons bijective) since linear maps preserve spans. dimension reasons $f$ must have nonzero kernel. By just requiring the restriction of $f$ to $X$ to be injective, you want all elements of $X$ to be non-congruent modulo the kernel of $f$.

This means that the difference (equivalently sum) of any two distinct elements of$~X$ is forbidden to be in $\ker f$. But by an appropriate choice of $X$ one can arrange that this excludes *every* nonzero vector from $\ker f$, forcing $f$ to be injective which we saw it cannot be. For $n=3$, four vectors only give $\binom42=6$ differences which cannot exhaust $7$ nonzero vectors, however with $n=4$ one has ample space for a counterexample; even just $6$ well chosen vectors will do. Concretely take $V=\Bbb F_2^4$ and 
$$X=\{(0,0,0,0),~(0,0,0,1),~(0,0,1,0),~(0,1,0,1),~(1,0,0,0),~(1,1,1,0)\}.
$$
One can easily check that all $15$ nonzero elements of the vector space can be written as a sum of two of these vectors. This means that any nonzero subspace contains the difference of two vectors, and so for a linear map $f:V\to V$ to restrict injectively to $X$, its kernel can contain only the zero vector. But then $f$ is an isomorphism and $Y=f(X)$ spans all of $V$; it is not contained in any subspace of dimension$~3$.

Comment: Thx! Nice counter example. I hope that you don't mind that I've taken the liberty of suggesting an edit to include the reasoning you give in the comment, in order to make the logic behind your answer clearer and more self-contained?